# Error: Schema engine error: ERROR: password authentication failed for user '', prisma, postgresql

Tags: postgresql, prisma, vercel

I have created Postgres database with Vercel, and when trying to migrate with command *npx prisma migrate dev* i receive:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma       
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "verceldb", schema "public" at "ep-curly-resonance-50034155.eu-central-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432"

Error: Schema engine error:
ERROR: password authentication failed for user ''
```

I'm weak in the backend and don't know how to help you understand the problem, so I'm leaving these prisma and .env codes in case you need them:

schema.prisma:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url = env("POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL") // uses connection pooling
  directUrl = env("POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING") // uses a direct connection
}

model Form {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  userId String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  published Boolean @default(false)
  name String
  description String @default("")
  content String @default("[]")

  visits Int @default(0)
  submissions Int @default(0)

  shareURL String @default(uuid())
  FormSubmissions FormSubmissions[]
}

model FormSubmissions {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  formId Int
  form Form @relation(fields: [formId], references: [id])

  content String
}
```

.env:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_test_aW1tZW5zZS1mYWxjb24tNzQuY2xlcmsuYWNjb3VudHMuZGV2JA
CLERK_SECRET_KEY=sk_test_w9Pc0w9eCvYrcl4iwogc28r2YLPbIyhKyZRAi8Sw7A

NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_IN_URL=/sign-in
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_SIGN_UP_URL=/sign-up
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_IN_URL=/
NEXT_PUBLIC_CLERK_AFTER_SIGN_UP_URL=/

# This was inserted by `prisma init`:
# Environment variables declared in this file are automatically made available to Prisma.
# See the documentation for more detail: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema#accessing-environment-variables-from-the-schema

# Prisma supports the native connection string format for PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, SQL Server, MongoDB and CockroachDB.
# See the documentation for all the connection string options: https://pris.ly/d/connection-strings

POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgres://:@ep-curly-resonance-50034155-pooler.eu-central-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb?pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=15"
POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgres://:@ep-curly-resonance-50034155.eu-central-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb"
```

Comment: Specify a user.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any user name and password in your `.env` file for PostgreSQL database.

A connection URL can also take arguments. Here is the same example from above with placeholder values in uppercase letters for three arguments:

```
postgresql://USER:PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/DATABASE?KEY1=VALUE&KEY2=VALUE&KEY3=VALUE
```

If you create your db on Versel, you need to find in tab `.env.local` environment variables named: `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` or just copy all of them and paste in your `.env` file.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't put the variable names here, put the actual values of that variables**

POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="postgres://POSTGRES_USER:POSTGRES_PASSWORD@ep-curly-resonance-50034155-pooler.eu-central-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb?pgbouncer=true&connect_timeout=15"

POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="postgres://POSTGRES_USER:POSTGRES_PASSWORD@ep-curly-resonance-50034155.eu-central-1.postgres.vercel-storage.com:5432/verceldb"

[env snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3zq2.png)

The values of POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD would be available in the snippet! You can view it in the link above!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).